# Use hover on div to change all elements inside that div

Tags: css, html, hover

My excuses in advance, since this seems to be a problem concerning very basic understanding of CSS and maybe also Javascript.

What I want to do is this: imagine a div which contains a h3 and a p. On hovering on the div I would like the h3 and p to change their font-weight. So far I am using this code here to change the opacity and border on hovering over the div, but I really don't know how I can refer to the two elements inside the div. I'm really sorry, but I need someone to explain it to me in very simple terms.

For example, I think those elements inside the div are called children, but I'm not even sure about that... I'm really working with all that HTML/CSS/Java stuff for the first time and try to figure things out as I go along. The tutorial sites I found so far couldn't solve my problem, therefore this post.

More background information: I'm using the ["smoothgallery" script](http://smoothgallery.jondesign.net/) by jondesign (Jonathan Schemoul) () and am trying to bend it to my will, but that is pretty difficult if you don't have any clue how it actually works. The site I implemented the script in can be found [here](http://org.scoutnet.de/dpsg/nrs/gallery/).

Here comes the CSS part that changes the div on hover:

```
.jdGallery .gallerySelector .gallerySelectorInner div.hover{
    border: 1px solid #89203B;
    border-left: 0.8em solid #89203B;
    background: url('../../images/teaserBox_bg.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    filter:alpha(opacity=1);
    -moz-opacity:1;      /
    -khtml-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This entry in the CSS file changes the settings for e.g. the h3 inside that div,

```
.jdGallery .gallerySelector .gallerySelectorInner div.galleryButton h3{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

You may also want to take a look at the .js file that makes these classes, it can be found [here](http://org.scoutnet.de/dpsg/nrs/gallery/scripts/jd.gallery.set.js).

This is probably the most important part here:

```
    createGalleryButtons: function () {
            var galleryButtonWidth =
                    ((this.galleryElement.offsetWidth - 30) / 2) - 14;
            this.gallerySet.each(function(galleryItem, index){
                    var button = new Element('div').addClass('galleryButton').injectInside(
                            this.gallerySelectorInner
                    ).addEvents({
                            'mouseover': function(myself){
                                    myself.button.addClass('hover');
                            }.pass(galleryItem, this),
                            'mouseout': function(myself){
                                    myself.button.removeClass('hover');
                            }.pass(galleryItem, this),
                            'click': function(myself, number){
                                    this.changeGallery.pass(number,this)();
                            }.pass([galleryItem, index], this)
                    }).setStyle('width', galleryButtonWidth);
                    galleryItem.button = button;
                    var thumbnail = "";
                    if (this.options.showCarousel)
                            thumbnail = galleryItem.elements[0].thumbnail;
                    else
                            thumbnail = galleryItem.elements[0].image;
                    new Element('div').addClass('preview').setStyle(
                            'backgroundImage',
                            "url('" + thumbnail + "')"
                    ).injectInside(button);
                    new Element('h3').set('html', galleryItem.title).injectInside(button);
                    new Element('p').addClass('info').set('html', formatString(this.options.textGalleryInfo, galleryItem.elements.length)).injectInside(button);
            }, this);
            new Element('br').injectInside(this.gallerySelectorInner).setStyle('clear','both');
    },
```

So my question here is, if it is possible at all to change the h3 and p settings by using the hover function on the main div?

Thanks in advance! Also for negative criticism, I don't really know if I did something wrong in the way I posted this question and if I can even ask it here.

Answer (score 33):

You're making this way more complicated than it needs to be. No Javascript is required to do this. Let's say you've got the following:

```html
<div class="container">
    <h3>This is a header</h3>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
</div>
```

So you've got a container, with a header and paragraph. Let's say you want to have the header normal weight, and the paragraph in red normally, with a padded box around the whole thing. Here are your styles:

```css
.container { border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px; }
.container h3 { font-weight: normal; }
.container p { color: red; }
```

When you hover the mouse over the , you want the paragraph and header in bold and the box border to change to blue. Add this into your stylesheet (or `<style>` block) *below* the CSS above:

```css
.container:hover { border-color: blue; }
.container:hover h3 { font-weight: bold; }
.container:hover p { font-weight: bold; }
```

Note that you can save a bit of space, and make it more concise by combining the `<h3>` and `<p>` styles into one line with a comma, since they're both the same. The whole thing would now look like this:

```css
.container { border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px; }
.container h3 { font-weight: normal; }
.container p { color: red; }
```

```css
.container:hover { border-color: blue; }
.container:hover h3, .container:hover p { font-weight: bold; }
```

Remember that the "C" in "CSS" stands for "cascading": styles cascade down through both hierarchies (that is, a parent element's style also applies to a child element, unless it's got default styles like margins or whatever), and down the style sheet - that means styles you define after others will override them if they apply to the same element.

The ":hover" selector in CSS can pretty much be used on anything, with very few exceptions. I use them regularly for Javascript-free drop-down menus. You can find more on the ":hover" CSS selector here: [W3Schools CSS reference on ":hover"](http://www.w3schools.com/css/sel_hover.asp). In fact, the [W3Schools site](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) is a generally great resource for brushing up your CSS.

Comment: Well, your answer helped me. But indirectly. I noticed that in my CSS file it really said div.hover, and not div:hover. 
My main problem was just that I don't know how I can adress certain sub-elements. I don't even know how to say that. I mean, I know that body {} changes everything for the tag "body", but when it comes to adressing one single h3 hidden in a lot of higher-ranked elements, I got lost a bit. As I said, I'm just figuring everything out as I go along, trying to make sense of some pages and scripts that someone else wrote. Now all that's left is to say: Thank you!!

Comment: Aha! Yes, that was the prompt for my explanation of the :hover CSS selector. Glad it got you in the right direction, then! When it comes to tricky stuff like finding the DOM nesting position of specific elements, I can't recommend enough tools like Firebug and Web Developer Toolbar for Firefox. Both allow you inspect elements by hovering the cursor over them, and they'll show you both where those elements are, and the effective CSS styles. Firebug will also show you precisely how those effective styles were computed, and how they cascaded down through CSS - invaluable.

Answer (score 3):

because short answers what we always prefer to look for:

```
.classname :hover *
```